# Redis vs Hazelcast as session store

Tags: redis, hazelcast, session-store

I was searching about solutions for clustering web sessions. I'm considering one of the following two approaches: one is with redis and the second one is with hazelcast.

Has anyone used in production any of the mentioned technologies, and with what results? I have also fallen into this: [Hazelcast's Web session clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286552/hazelcasts-web-session-clustering). Is there any of the two solutions proven to be problematic? And in what way

Thank you for your time

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Hazelcast.

We have customers using the Hazelcast session replication without problems.

I don't have any experience with Redis and session clustering.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, and what is the suggested, if possible, maximum number of instances running with session replication? each instance carries all the sessions of all the concurrent users? I'm asking to make a rough calculation of the memory requirements